# How to make bulk upsert in nested collection in MongoDb C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-.net-driver

For instance, we have a collection:

```
{
   "Request":{
      "RequestCode":1,
      "Note":"test updated",
      "Results":[
         {
            "ResultCode":1,
            "Name":"Test",
            "Value":10
         },
         {
            "ResultCode":2,
            "Name":"Second result",
            "Value":15
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In the next operation we received:

```
{
   "Request":{
      "RequestCode":1,
      "Note":"test updated again",//UPDATED
      "Results":[
         {
            "ResultCode":1,
            "Name":"Test",
            "Value":15  //UPDATED
         },
         {
            "ResultCode":2,
            "Name":"Second result",
            "Value":15
         },
         { //ADDED
            "ResultCode":3,
            "Name":"Third result",
            "Value":14
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

1. I need to create request if it doesn't exist and update it if it
   exists.
2. For a nested collection I need to insert element if a result
   with some ResultCode doesn't exists or update/replace if a result
   with some ResultCode exists.

Is it possible to do bulk upsert in MongoDb? Or I just have to at first check if request exists and then update all values inside it or create it and after that go through all results in received collection and check if some ResultCode exists in already saved collection? If yes then update all fields inside , if no then insert result in Results collection

Could you please recommend any good sources with mongodb examples for c#?

Comment: What is a nested collection?

Comment: @D.SM In this example the nested collection is "Results". I would like to know if it's possible to make Bulk update in MongoDb ?

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/.

Answer (score 0):

Currently my solution looks like this:

```
var collection = GetCollection();

        var filter = Builders<Request>.Filter.Eq(e => e.RequestCode, model.RequestCode);
        var definition = Builders<Request>.Update
            .SetOnInsert(e => e.RequestCode, model.RequestCode)
            .Set(e => e.Note, model.Note)
            .SetOnInsert(e => e.Results, new List<Result>());

        await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, definition, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });

        var currentRequest = await FindOneAsync(x => x.RequestCode == model.RequestCode);

        foreach (var result in model.Results)
        {
            var currentResult = currentRequest.Results.FirstOrDefault(
                e => e.ResultCode == result.ResultCode);

            if (currentResult == null)
            {
                currentRequest.Results.Add(new Result
                {
                    ResultCode = result.ResultCode,
                    Name = result.Name,
                    Value = result.Range
                });
            }
            else
            {
                currentResult.ResultCode = result.ResultCode;
                currentResult.Name = result.Name;
                currentResult.Value= result.Value;
            }

        }

        await collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(e => e.RequestCode== request.RequestCode, currentRequest);
```

Maybe it's possible to make it better?